# Is my iPad 2 a "Rev A"?

Tags: ipad, ipsw

After spending some time searching with Google and on developer.apple.com, I still can't figure whether my iPad 2 is a "Rev A" or not (its model is MC979LL/A).

How can I know my exact model?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't have a Rev A iPad 2 — the MC979 is an iPad2,1 (16 GB White).

The Rev A iPad 2 (iPad2,4 — A1395) model numbers start with **MC954** (black) or **MC989** (white). They use the [Apple A5 Rev A](http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/S5L8942).

<sup>Source: [The iPhone Wiki — Models](http://theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Models)</sup>

To view your model number, you can find it in Settings → About.

Comment: Thanks, I'll accept in 7 minutes when the system lets me. While we're here, how do you know this?

Comment: @Yar Added the source :)

Comment: Thank you, the concern is that the document linked doesn't mention "Rev A" nor "Revision A" etc... so how would a person who is not you know this? Thanks!

Comment: @Yar The iPad 2 Rev A is the iPad2,4 — the last model of iPad 2. Edited answer to clarify.

Comment: Thanks, as you well know, we're creating content for the Internet here, so I will be the last person to suffer. Thank you!