# Is my refurbished iPad 2 a Model A?

Tags: ios, ipad

I recently acquired a refurbished iPad 2 WiFi and, being an iOS developer, I would like to use it as a test device and load beta iOS versions on it.  Apple offers two different downloads, one for an "iPad 2" and one for an "iPad 2 (Model A)."  I'm not sure which one I can safely use.  [This Ask Different answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/120786/is-my-ipad-2-a-rev-a) states that iPad 2's with model number MC979 are not Rev A, whereas A1395 MC954 (black) or MC989 (white) are Model A's.  My iPad 2 has "Model A1395" written on the back, however in Settings -> General -> About, it lists the Model as FC769LL/A.  Is mine a Model A or not?

Comment: What makes an iPad an version A or not?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the *Version A* is the iPad 2 that came out in March 2012 and was only sold in a 16GB version. It has a revised A5 CPU and it's **Model Identifier** is *[iPad2,4](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/ipad/specs/apple-ipad-2-wi-fi-ipad24-2012-specs.html)*.

The two numbers you're referring to, provide different information.

The one on the back cover is the actual **Model Number**, which in this case is *A1395*, whereas the one retrieved from *Settings / General / About* is the **Order Number**, and holds information regarding **when** and **where** the device was made, its **colour** and **storage**.